# Calender is not populating in Mozilla emulator mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[Attached is the error image for emulator version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPdS3.png)

I am testing my application in different browser, The application having calender which is loading correctly in other browser but its not showing field as calender while checking on mozilla 67.0 emulator mode even its showing calender in the browser mode of mozilla.

Please let me know where i am doing wrong or where do i need to make changes. Thanks in advance.

```html
 

 <label for="bankTrans">{{ 'PAGE_ORDERASTRO_BANKTRANS' | translate }}</label>
                    <input type="date" name="bankTrans" ng-model="orderAstro.paymentDate" class="form-control" id="bankTrans"
                        ng-disabled="isDisabled" required />
```

Comment: check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) maybe this helps you

Comment: Thanks, Gone thru that link already. Nothing productive found

Comment: did you try in chrome developers tools? same behavior? what if you download and install a browser extension which lets you emulate on a mobile device, same behavior?

Comment: The code and information provided is not enough to investigate what could cause this. Do you get any JS errors in the console? And what exactly is Mozilla emulator mode? Since google does not know this exact term. Firefox responsive design mode?

Comment: NO i am not getting any error on console..Let me know what else you require as this is the only thing i am using in HTML

Comment: @AkberIqbal : The code is working good in both browser & emulator mode in Chrome only the problem is coming is with the mozila emulator

Comment: This would mean that Mozilla emulator is not accurate... Having said that, test on an actual device before you deploy to prod

Comment: There is no approach we can try to populate it on EMulator and how can you say that there is problem in emulator.